# How to create Dynamic Menu in CK editor using javascript?

Tags: ckeditor, contextmenu

How to create Dynamic Menu in  CK editor using javascript ?

Please See the screen shot of current working code for details.
[image]
[image]

I want dynamic context menu

if array has 2 words means need to create and show only words in context menu need to reduce the context menu length,

if array has 4 words menas need to create context menu for four words

Here result is declared as array.

```
            var ckedit ;
             editor.on('instanceReady', function (e) {
             var e = e.editor;
             ckedit = e;   
            e.addMenuGroup("cv_people", 100);
             e.addMenuItems({ 
          // Addmenu context menu
                     cv: {
                        label: "Suggestions",
                        group: "cv",
                        getItems: function () {
                        ckedit.addCommand("cv1", {
                        exec: function (ckedit) {
                        ckedit.insertText(result[0]);
                        }
                    });
                        ckedit.addCommand("cv2", {
                        exec: function (ckedit) {
                        ckedit.insertText(result[1]);
                        }
                    });
                    ckedit.addCommand("cv3", {
                        exec: function (ckedit) {
                        ckedit.insertText(result[2]);
                        }
                    });
                    ckedit.addCommand("cv4", {
                        exec: function (ckedit) {
                        ckedit.insertText(result[3]);
                        }
                    });

                   return {
                            cv1: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON,
                            cv2: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF,
                            cv3: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF,
                            cv4: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF,
                            };
                        }
                   }
              });
           }
              cv1: {
                        label: " ",
                        group: "cv_people",
                        getItems: function () {
                            //alert("ok");
                        }
                    },
                    cv2: {
                        label: " ",
                        group: "cv_people",
                        getItems: function () {
                            //alert("ok");
                        }
                    },
                    cv3: {
                        label: " ",
                        group: "cv_people",
                        getItems: function () {
                            //alert("ok");
                        }
                    },
                    cv4: {
                        label: " ",
                        group: "cv_people",
                        getItems: function () {
                            //alert("ok");
                        }
                    },
```

Please help me to get contextmenu in dynamic.

Please See the screen shot of current working code.

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're facing. Is it the height of the context menu?

Comment: from a array i got some number of values.at the time of right click data will be come from a web service.for example 1 st time array length is 4 and second length is 7.For 1st time we need to show 4 values in context menu,second context menu  count must be increased as 7. please help to done this .thanks in advance

Comment: So what is stopping you?  From your screenshots it looks like you have that. First screenshot shows 1 item in the context menu. The second shows 4 items

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE] (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

Since you didn't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I should do a lot of guesses. Also your current code is quite strange. For example why do you need so many copies of variables all linking to the same `CKEditor` instance (`editor`, `ckedit` and the "redefined" `e` inside listener)? I'll use only `ckedit` which I assume you get using something like:

```js
var ckedit = CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor', some config);
```

I also assume that you have some global variable `results` that is sometimes updated with AJAX results. I'll use a fixed one instead.

```js
var results = ["A", "BB", "CCC", "DDDD"];
```

So what you need is something like this

```js
ckedit.on('instanceReady', function (ee) {
    ckedit.addMenuGroup("cv_people", 100);
    ckedit.addMenuGroup("cv_sub", 100);
    ckedit.addMenuItems({
        cv: {
            label: "Suggestions",
            group: "cv_people",
            getItems: function () {
                var menuItems = {};
                var states = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    // create scope for "local" i that we use in onClick closure
                    (function (i) {
                        var key = "cv_" + i;
                        menuItems[key] = {
                            label: results[i],
                            group: "cv_sub",
                            onClick: function () {
                                ckedit.insertText(results[i]);
                                //alert(results[i]);
                            }
                        };
                        states[key] = CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF;
                    })(i);
                }

                ckedit.addMenuItems(menuItems);

                return states;
            }
        }
    });

    ckedit.contextMenu.addListener(function (element, selection) {
        return {
            cv: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF
        };
    });
});
```

Here the idea is that you create menu groups and the top level "Suggestions" menu item beforehand; and create (or re-create) child `menuItems` and their `states` on-demand when the top-level `getItems` is called by just filling corresponding container objects with values for auto-generated keys `var key = "cv_" + i;`.